# I can't find Java among the categories when I press on "New Project" in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8, new-project, netbeans-8.2

I have a problem with NetBeans that when I click on New Project I find only C/C++ category and no Java category:

[image: Project Wizard]

I already have JDK installed in my computer and among the paths in "System variables". I can't find Java in *NetBeans > Tools > Plugins > Installed* either.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have the necessary Java plugins installed, but they are not yet activated.

If you select **Tools > Plugins > Installed**, does the entry for **Java SE** look like this?...

[image: Java SE not activated.]

If the **Activated** icon for Java SE is gray then you need to:

- Select the **Java SE** entry and check it.
- Click the **Activate** button.

After that the **Active** icon should be a white check mark with a green background:

[image: Java SE activated.]

You can then use the project wizard for basic Java projects. To create a simple "*Hello world!*" application select **File > New Project... > Java with Ant > Java Application**.

[image: Java project wizard]

Notes:

- NetBeans 11.0 supports multiple languages, and most functionality is not activated by default. This is because a JavaScript or PHP or C++ developer may have no use for Java functionality, and vice versa.
- If you want to do JavaFX 2 and/or Java EE development you will also need to activate their plugins from the **Installed** tab shown in the screen shots above.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation but I already said in the question that I can't find Java in _NetBeans > Tools > Plugins > Installed_ either.

Comment: @Bubbaloo My mistake entirely, and my apologies. I incorrectly assumed that you were using the current version of NetBeans, but I see that your issue is with NetBeans 8.2. My answer is irrelevant for your problem and I will correct it.

Comment: @Bubbaloo I have tried unsuccessfully to reproduce your problem by uninstalling all the Java plugins on NetBeans 8.2, but even after doing that I still see **Java** listed in the **Categories** of the Project Wizard. Could you check the NetBeans log (**View > IDE Log**) and update your question if there are any relevant error messages in that log? Also, could you add a screen shot of the **Installed** tab of the **Tools > Plugins** screen?